# Query all MMS addr entries

Tags: android, mms

Is there a way of getting all mms addr entries in one query instead one entry (or group of entries) at a time? i.e. something like:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/addr");
Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

I can't do this the normal way because I need all the records in the addr table and sometimes don't have all the message ID's to build the URI.